# Laser tattoo removal

Tags: laser, biophysics

1. I would like to know if someone could please briefly explain how laser technology of tattoo removal works?
2. And second, could there possibly be any dangers to cells, specially on bones?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics

Comment: please dont close. i need to find the answer..soon.

Comment: I take it back, I think there is some [very interesting physics involved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tattoo_removal#Mechanism_of_laser_action)!

Comment: Related: [Why do tattoos persist if body cells are regularly renewed?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36712/why-do-tattoos-persist-if-body-cells-are-regularly-renewed/36713#36713)

Answer (score 3):

I will explain the basic idea. The ink that is in the skin is just metallic particles that on average have bigger size than the one the white cells can "fight" and remove from the system. Although the body recognizes the "alien" particles living in the skin and constantly fights them (and this is the reason the tattoo wears out) it is unable to remove big chunks of particles. The laser targets into the "big" chunks of metallic particles of the ink so that it splits them into much smaller such that the body can expel them (through white cells maybe). In the end the tattoo is basically removed from the urine system.

This is a [video explaining the above](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0B7F5UbTOQ) in detail by the Youtube program "Smarter every day".

Comment: but could there be damage made to cells this way? i mean dna damage and then cancer because of this treatment ...

Comment: Well, some damage is due for, sure, but not cancer in any case. It is not a powerful laser and it is quite targeted. It might produce small burns but nothing major. Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0B7F5UbTOQ

Comment: The video is a very good source of information - may I recommend that you add it to your answer? Comments tend to disappear over time...

Comment: And one nitpick - according to your video link the particles end up in the liver not the kidney - so they don't come out through the urine but through the stool (you poop them out)

Answer (score -1):

Any thoughts on the second question?

Could laser damage the dna, or perhaps bones, which could result in some cell damage-cancer? How deep laser go? What I need to know about it?